# Can't remove a view included using a include tag

Tags: android

Removing a view that was included using a `<include>` tag seems to have no effect.

```
ViewGroup currentPersonContainer = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(R.id.propria_pessoa_container);
if (dto.occupation!= null) {
    .
    .
    .                   
} else {
    root.removeView(currentPersonContainer);
}
```

After the `root.removeView(currentPersonContainer);` I can still find it in root and the view is still visible.

How can I remove a view included in a xml layout resource file?

Comment: Is the `currentPersonContainer` a direct child of `currentPersonContainer`?

Comment: No, it is not. Hmm, that may be is the problem.

Comment: Just tell us how currentPersonContainer and root are lelated to each other? XML file maybe?

Comment: It worked, I removed from the direct parent. @SimonMarquis can you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: How would you like I edit it?

Comment: Not much, just add this information about the direct child thing and that I can also do it using the snippet given. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `<include>` tag, you have to **reassign** the `id`.

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <include 
        layout="@layout/layout_to_include"
        android:id="@+id/some_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The included view will be accessible through `some_id` now. You can verify this by checking if, in your current setup, `currentPersonContainer` is initialized to `null`. I think it is.  And `removeView(View)` fails silently on when `view` is null.

In short, it doesn't matter if your actual layout has an id set on the root element, you still need to assign an `id` inside the `<include />` tag.

Comment: I was able to find and update it using the findViewById() method. I was just not able to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this view by calling:

```
((ViewGroup)(currentPersonContainer.getParent()).removeView(currentPersonContainer);
```

This will remove the view from its direct parent.

Comment: This will cause a `NullPointerException`.